# Vue.JS value tied on input having the focus

Tags: vue.js, onfocus

Is there a way to change a value in the model when an input gets/loses focus?

The use case here is a search input that shows results as you type, these should only show when the focus is on the search box.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<input type="search" v-model="query">
<div class="results-as-you-type" v-if="magic_flag"> ... </div>
```

And then,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#search_wrapper',
  data: {
    query: '',
    magic_flag: false
  }
});
```

The idea here is that `magic_flag` should turn to `true` when the search box has focus. I could do this manually (using jQuery, for example), but I want a pure Vue.JS solution.

Comment: See https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/1005/a-set-of-directives-to-manage-focus

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Apparently, this is as simple as doing a bit of code on [event handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

```html
<input 
  type="search" 
  v-model="query"
  @focus="magic_flag = true"
  @blur="magic_flag = false"
/>
<div class="results-as-you-type" v-if="magic_flag"> ... </div>
```

Comment: You could also write methods and call them, instead of putting too much logic into template.But this way is totally fine.

Comment: I don't see focus and blur on both the docs and api for vue, is it listed somewhere that I've missed?

Comment: @KelvinZhao they are native js events, that's why they are not listed in the Vue docs.

Comment: Focus is something that probably change often, you might want to use "v-show" instead of "v-if"   https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show

Answer (score 7):

Another way to handle something like this in a more complex scenario might be to allow the form to track which field is currently active, and then use a watcher.

I will show a quick sample:

```
<input
    v-model="user.foo"
    type="text"
    name="foo"
    @focus="currentlyActiveField = 'foo'"
>

<input
    ref="bar"
    v-model="user.bar"
    type="text"
    name="bar"
    @focus="currentlyActiveField = 'bar'"
>
```

...

```
data() {
    return {
        currentlyActiveField: '',
        user: {
            foo: '',
            bar: '',
        },
    };
},

watch: {
    user: {
        deep: true,
        handler(user) {
            if ((this.currentlyActiveField === 'foo') && (user.foo.length === 4)) {
                // the field is focused and some condition is met
                this.$refs.bar.focus();
            }
        },
    },
},
```

In my sample here, if the currently-active field is `foo` and the value is 4 characters long, then the next field `bar` will automatically be focused. This type of logic is useful when dealing with forms that have things like credit card number, credit card expiry, and credit card security code inputs. The UX can be improved in this way.

I hope this could stimulate your creativity. Watchers are handy because they allow you to listen for changes to your data model and act according to your custom needs at the time the watcher is triggered.

In my example, you can see that each input is named, and the component knows which input is currently focused because it is tracking the `currentlyActiveField`.

The watcher I have shown is a bit more complex in that it is a "deep" watcher, which means it is capable of watching Objects and Arrays. Without `deep: true`, the watcher would only be triggered if `user` was reassigned, but we don't want that. We are watching the keys `foo` and `bar` on `user`.

Behind the scenes, `deep: true` is adding observers to all keys on `this.user`. Without `deep` enabled, Vue reasonably does not incur the cost of maintaining every key reactively.

A simple watcher would be like this:

```
watch: {
    user() {
        console.log('this.user changed');
    },
},
```

Note: If you discover that where I have `handler(user) {`, you could have `handler(oldValue, newValue) {` but you notice that both show the same value, it's because both are a reference to the same `user` object. Read more here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2164

> Edit: to avoid deep watching, it's been a while, but I think you can actually watch a key like this:

```
watch: {
    'user.foo'() {
        console.log('user foo changed');
    },
},
```

But if that doesn't work, you can also definitely make a computed prop and then watch that:

```
computed: {
    userFoo() {
        return this.user.foo;
    },
},

watch: {
    userFoo() {
        console.log('user foo changed');
    },
},
```

I added those extra two examples so we could quickly note that deep watching will consume more resources because it triggers more often. I personally avoid deep watching in favour of more precise watching, whenever reasonable.

However, in this example with the `user` object, if all keys correspond to inputs, then it is reasonable to deep watch. That is to say it might be.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flat by determinate a special **CSS** `class`, for example this a simple snippet:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  content: 'click to change content',
  flat_input_active: false
 },
 methods: {
  onFocus: function(event) {
          event.target.select();
          this.flat_input_active = true;
  },
  onBlur: function(event) {
          this.flat_input_active = false;
  }
 },
 computed: {
  clazz: function() {
   var clzz = 'control-form';
   if (this.flat_input_active == false) {
    clzz += ' only-text';
   }
   return clzz;
  }
 }
});
```

```css
#app {
  background: #EEE;
}
input.only-text { /* special css class */
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- libraries -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<!-- html template -->
<div id='app'>
 <h1>
 <input v-model='content' :class='clazz'
  @focus="onFocus($event)"
  @blur="onBlur"/>
 </h1>
<div>
```

**Good luck**

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to activate the search when the user mouses over the input - @mouseover=...

Another approach to this kind of functionality is that the filter input is always active, even when the mouse is in the result list.  Typing any letters modifies the filter input without changing focus.  Many implementations actually show the filter input box only after a letter or number is typed.

Look into @event.capture.